# How to draw lines statically before paint event?

Tags: c#, .net, graphics

I'm creating a spectrum analyzer and I want to make it gridded. My spectrum will be painted over a panel in a windows forms application. When I draw lines inside panel_Paint function which is tied to panel's paint event, It redraws 2048/48000 times a second because it is a real time FFT spectrum with the FFT size of 2048 and sampling rate of 48000. Here is my way of drawing lines inside the paint function:

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
       for (int i = 0; i < panel1.Width; i+= panel1.Width / 20)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < panel1.Height; j+= panel1.Height / 20)
                {
                    g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, i, j, i, panel1.Height + j);
                    g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, i, j, panel1.Width + i, j);
                }
            }
}
```

Here is the spectrum after lines:
[image: griddedspectrum]

I like how spectrum looks but while computation there is no time for the spectrum while waiting for the lines to be redrawn.

Note: The above image is an instant(single fft block) screen shot of the spectrum. As I mentioned above, spectrum is not readable while performing real-time application.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: I would recommend that you avoid redrawing the grid. You could have two surfaces to paint on the bottom one holds your grid and the top one for your spectrum trace. Give the spectrum trace layer a transparent background

Comment: "It redraws 2048 times a second", this seem unnecessary, since few screens can update more than 144hz.

Comment: @JonasH you pointed something right, actually i typed it wrong, the screen is updated every 2048/48000(fft size /sampling rate) seconds, not 2048 times per second. thank you.

Comment: You can use a background image, maybe dynamically prepared for the panel, or, recommended, a Picturebox.  Note, that straight lines draw really really fast. And Drawing faster that 2x25fps it not visible for a human observer anyway. Panels in Winformas are not really meant to be drawn upon. If you stick to a Panel, make sure it is double-buffered.

Comment: @ChrisBD I just tried to make what you said, I used 2 panels, one of which is transparent. But invalidating one of the panels causes the other panel to invalidate as well even though I set 'invalidateChildren' to false while invalidating the parent. What should i do to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I used the wrong tools for this job, when processing real time data, you should make computations really fast before displaying it. And when It came to displaying, double buffering the parent display tool works like "magic".

As I mentioned in the question above, I was using panel over the form while drawing the spectrum, when I removed the panel and changed the whole form to a UserControl, I was able to do double buffering that I couldn't do in the panel and the whole problem was solved.

When the DoubleBuffered property is set to true, the current drawing data is written to a second buffer before being drawn on the surface on which the drawing will be made, then the data in this second buffer is quickly written to the memory where the drawing will be made. Voila! Flickering is prevented.

The code inside the UserControl's load function:

```
this.DoubleBuffered = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Making a real-time application with graphics is not trivial. Several points:

1. Painting at 2048 Hz is not usefull for the viewer, the screen usually refreshes at 60 Hz because our eyes cannot observe faster changes.
2. The paint event is meant to paint everything in one go, so gridlines and the FFT graph.
3. You can trigger the paint event by calling `Control.Invalidate()` or in this case `Control.Refresh()` might give a more pleasant refresh. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate
4. It might be necessary to move the code that collects the signal and calculates the FFT spectrum to a background thread, where you have much more control over its timing and can process the data uninterrupted.

So a possible way of organizing the application would be like this:

- Have a background thread do the heavy work and collect data in a buffer data structure.
- Put a timer on the UI Form that calls `Control.Refresh()` periodically. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer
- Have the paint event handler read all the data prepared in the buffer and clear it. And then use that data to paint a FFT graph. Combining all the data from multiple FFT blocks.
- Make sure the buffer can contain multiple FFT bocks by using a suitable data structure like a `ConcurrentQueue<T>`  where T is of a Type that contains one FFT block. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1

There is a lot of information around about how to communicate from a background thread to a foreground thread like the one that is handling the paint events. So I'm not going to duplicate that here. But done right it makes your application run smooth and responsive.

Combining multiple FFT blocks into one graph drawing is a challenge. So, at first, keep that part simple by for example discarding all but the most recent block. Then when everything else works improve on the design of this part.

Also start with a paint timer set to 20 Hz or there about and increase it from there. Because the graphics system might not like to many paint actions.

Comment: as JonasH pointed out, I edited my question with the correct redrawing time, which was nearly 25 Hz. However spectrum is not much readable. You summed up the process very well. I'll look into your suggestions for improving the program. Even I haven't tried @ChrisBD's answer on making the panel gridded yet but I found it closer to the answer to this question. Thank you.

Comment: I only realized the mistake after reading JonasH's comment. 25 Hz won't topple the graphics system, so trying to combine multiple blocks is not a problem that needs solving right now.